# Does Joomla CMS or Joomla Framework provide any Class for making POST request to an external API?

Tags: joomla-api, restful-api

I came across:

- [the documentation for Joomla's HTTP client class](https://api.joomla.org/framework-1/classes/Joomla.Http.Http.html) and
- [joomla/http in packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/joomla/http)

Are they the same thing? Are these capable of sending POST requests to an external API?

Answer (score 1):

As you might already figured out, yes its the same and yes thats the way it works...

As described in the manual:

```
use Joomla\Http\HttpFactory;

// Create an instance of a default Http object.
$http = Http\HttpFactory::getHttp();


// Prepare the update data.
$data = array('make' => 'Holden', model => 'EJ-Special');

// Invoke the GET request.

$response = $http->post('http://api.example.com/cars/1', $data);
```

HavFun!